# Are there major research areas in math? Or is it a lot of individual efforts?

Tags: soft-question

In physics, for example, dark matter is a major research area now. And there are specific parts of that trending. Is there anything similar in math? Is there something the majority of mathematicians agree is a major current problem? Or is it more or less everyone doing their thing?

Comment: A blend of both (as in any serious academic field), but this seems more appropriate at acadameia stack exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is technically about research-level math, it seems unlikely that the author has done the relevant background study for it.

Answer (score 8):

There are about 100 big research areas in mathematics, each of which is subdivided into several dozen smaller areas: see the AMS subject classification [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html). So it is fair to say that there are several thousand research directions within mathematics. Within these, mathematicians publish more than 100 thousand papers each year.

There are many big problems on which mathematicians agree. For these, I recommend you to read the [Notices of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/notices) and the [Bulletin of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/bull). You can also start your exploration [here](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems).

Finally, note that this site is for research mathematicians (who already know the answer to your question).

Comment: Please do not delete this answer (and the question)... This is useful for some one who wants to give an idea of what is going on mathematics to some one from other science streams...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The question is closed now. But you can vote to reopen it...